# Vim delay when using Ctrl+C, but only in SQL files

Tags: vim, gvim

I'm working on a side project with both JavaScript and SQL source files. When I'm editing the JavaScript, Vim behaves normally. However, when I'm editing the SQL files, there's about a one-second delay between when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and when Vim exits insert mode. When I use the Escape key, or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> which I mapped in my `~/.vimrc` as a test, it shows no delay.

I thought perhaps it was something to do with the syntax highlighting, but when I ran `:syntax off` to try and fix it, the delay still showed up. I also tried `:setf text`, which also did not work. I have only a couple of plugins installed (CtrlP, NerdTree, and highlighters for Jade, Less, and CoffeeScript) so I don't think that's what's interfering.

Does anyone know what could be going on?

Comment: What is `ttimeoutlen` value?

Comment: Does `:map` show anything for CTRL-C? What if you `:set filetype=text` and try?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You seem to have a *filetype plugin* that installs a buffer-local mapping for Ctrl-C. You can check with

```
:verbose imap <buffer> <C-c>
```

It's probably the default one, cp. `:help ft_sql`. The prefix key can be reconfigured via this (in your `~/.vimrc`):

```
let g:ftplugin_sql_omni_key = '<C-j>'
```